# How to enable/add a BackButton on the NavigationController?

Tags: c#, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have tried many ways, but haven't succeeded.

**In this way I can create a new UIBarButtonItem and it works, the problem is that it dosent  lock like a backButton/ArrowBackButton:**

```
            public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated) 
            { 
               base.ViewWillAppear (animated);  


               this.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem  ("Tillbaka", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
               this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated (true);  
                    }); 

            }
```

Have tried this, but haven't worked:

```
      public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
     {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated); 

            this.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(false,true);

         }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With MonoTouch.Dialog you have to set a "pushing" flag in order for it to show the back button. You can do this in the constructor, as indicated below:

```
public class MyViewController : DialogViewController
{
    public MyViewController
        : base(new RootElement("foo"), true)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works perfectly!

A RootElement is the top-level container for the items that go into a DVC.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give some context to this please? How is this ViewController being added to the NavigationController ?

If you use the PushViewController method (as below) then a back button will be automatically added.

```
var viewController = new UIViewController();
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController, true);
```

Comment: I use the PushViewController method so I get to My view.

I can also mention that the first Controller is a DialogViewController from Monotouch.Dialog.

Comment: I would be interested to see your code as to how you vc is created and pushed onto the nav controller as the back button should definitely be handled for you.